# Logging the method or class name always write the Common.Logging method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm using **log4net** with **.NET Common.Logging**. I configured a message pattern to include method and class name like so:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%-5level [%M %C] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

The problem is I always get the name of the Common.Logging method  and class:

```
FATAL [Fatal Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger] - log message
INFO  [Info Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger] - log message
DEBUG [Debug Common.Logging.Factory.AbstractLogger] - log message
```

It is most unuseful. Is there a way of printing **my method name**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to modify Common.Logging. In the file Log4NetLogger.cs replace the following line

```
private readonly static Type declaringType = typeof(Log4NetLogger);
```

with

```
private readonly static Type declaringType = typeof(AbstractLogger);
```

This should do the trick. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049992/when-using-wrapper-how-to-preserve-class-and-method-name-for-log4net-to-log/3448439#3448439) is some explanation why this should work.

Comment: You are right. There is an open bug associated for this task: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3044182&group_id=182424&atid=901156

Comment: The issue was opened on 2010-08-13 but is still opened Common.Logging 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This format works with my config

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%-5level [%logger] - %message%newline" />
</layout>
```

My logger is defined as

```
private static readonly Common.Logging.ILog logger = 
              Common.Logging.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I use these unmodified dlls

- Common.Logging.dll ver 2.0.0.0
- Common.Logging.Log4Net.dll ver 2.0.0.0
- log4net.dll ver 1.2.10

Update:
In the logging messages i add the methodname into the logging call as text so i have no performance overhead with analysing the call stack to get the methodname.

Comment: You are right. this solves the class name problem. The method name is a much bigger one, especially since I don't want to use reflection to get the method name all the time - only when I configure it so.