# Using Log4Net inside an interface

Tags: dependency-injection, log4net

I have an interface

```
public interface ILoggerService
{
    void Info(string message);
    void Warn(string message);
}
```

Then, i have a class which implements this interface and logs using Log4Net

```
public class Log4NetLoggerService : ILoggerService
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
    public Log4NetLoggerService()
    {
        // this always returns Log4NetLoggerService class type
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        _logger.Info(message);
    }
}
```

This works fine, but the problem is that if i want to log the current class and method name, (using %class - %M), this always returns `Log4NetLoggerService` as the class, and as the method it returns `Info` as the method.

I need to get the "parent" class type, which called the logging method.

Can i inject somehow the type of the class which calls the log methods when i create the `ILoggerService` instance?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the log4net source code; specifically how they implemented the ILog interface. You basically cannot use the ILog interface in your wrapper, instead you use the internal logger which accepts a parameter that instructs log4net where to look for the correct class / method in the call stack. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3448439/106567).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if you need the name of the class you're logging in, you're probably logging too much and from too many places in your application. This can lead to maintenance problems. Take a look at [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915056/264697) to verify if you're not logging too much and if you're not violating the SOLID principles.